# How can nested subdirectories and symbolic links be used without conflict with a multi-site Drupal installation?

Tags: 6, multi-sites

My question is basically a reflection of the question found here (which unfortunately does not have a clear answer): http://groups.drupal.org/node/20604

Please note that this is not a question about multi-site setup, but it is rather a question about a complicated edge-case; please read through before jumping to suggestions. Also, take a look at the link above if you need more info.

Note also multi-site works generally fine, just not this case.

Some truths:

- I am using symbolic links (on RHEL5 to be exact)
- I am using Drupal 6.20
- I am using Apache
- I am using subdirectories (NOT subdomains, switching to subdomains is *not* an acceptable answer)
- My Drupal site directories are nested two levels deep (e.g. `/campus/bus`, `/campus/news`)
- The Drupal sites all use the same code base in the `/campus` directory
- The Drupal sites all use different (their own) databases

In my case, there are dozens of sites, but the first conflict I noticed was as follows. There are two sites at urls such as the below structure:

```
drupal.drupalsite.com/campus/bus

drupal.drupalsite.com/campus/news
```

In the `sites/[foldername]` the respective folders are:

```
drupal.drupalsite.com.campus.bus

drupal.drupalsite.com.campus.news
```

The campus folder in the web root contains the Drupal install, and also the symbolic links, so in `/var/www/campus` there are e.g., `news -> ./`, `bus -> ./`.

On the 'bus' subsite, attempting to go to `https://drupalsite.com/campus/bus/news` makes Drupal confused. It seems to drop everything in the request after the last directory. e.g., `drupalsite.com/campus/bus/news` will instead resolve to `drupalsite.com/campus/bus` and `drupalsite.com/campus/bus/news/headlines` will return a `404 not found`.

For another data point, I put a `var_dump` on `$dir` in the `conf_path()` function to see how many directories were being looked at for each request. For a non-conflicting URL, such as bus/undergraduate-programs I got the following:

```
drupal.drupalsite.com.campus.bus
```

However for a conflicting URL such as bus/news/headlines I get

```
drupal.drupalsite.com.campus.bus.news
drupalsite.com.campus.bus.news
com.campus.bus.news
drupal.drupalsite.com.campus.bus
```

There is a patch which could allow the multi-site setup to be done via sites.php instead of via the method of using symbolic links, however it would involve hacking core, and thus I am not willing to entertain it, though for reference it is here: http://drupal.org/node/231298#comment-3769752

To note, I also tried most of the suggestions in the original groups.drupal.org. thread as well as numerous hacks in .htaccess and my `httpd.conf` file, all to no avail.  Please comment if you need further information to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using just one rewrite? I have this exact setup, and I take care of it with a separate rewrite for each sub-directory. If you just use the default index.php rewrite, the path gets rewritten back to the default, like drupal.drupalsite.com/index.php?q=/campus/news which is where the 404 comes from. I also use aliases in the server level config instead of symbolic links. It makes things cleaner. (Alias /campus/bus /var/www/html/whatever)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /campus/bus/
RewriteRule ^(.)$ /campus/bus/?q=$1  [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /campus/news/
RewriteRule ^(.)$ /campus/news/?q=$1  [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?q=$1  [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This looks promising. Just to be clear are you doing the RewriteCond in the .htaccess and then your server aliases in your httpd.conf (or whichever Apache conf file) ?

Comment: I add both the aliases and the rewrites in custom .conf files in /etc/httpd/conf.d. If you have control over the server there is no reason to use .htaccess files. I have the aliases in my VirtualHost directive and the rewrites in a Directory directive. (the relevant /var/www/html/whatever)

Comment: Great, ok, I'll give this a shot tomorrow night and then report back if this works as the correct answer.

Comment: Well, thanks, but no dice. Perhaps with some more info on how you setup your apache conf files I could get this to work, but currently when trying this, the site root still resolves correctly but anything past that ends up at something like /campus/bus/campus/campus/campus/campus/campus...

Comment: Did you remove the symbolic links? If you didn't you'll probably end up in loops. If it is a rewrite loop, you can turn on the rewrite log to see what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the setup you have at the moment in sub directories, is a little non standard, and may not be widely supported.

Given that you are already of piste, a small patch to core may be worth trying. Especially as the patch is in D7.

Or you could just switch to D7. No core hackery needed.

Comment: Well, I appreciate the answer, however as stated, switching to D7 and hacking core are both not answers. We have a roadmap to switch to D7 once 90% of the modules we use have stable D7 releases, and then I will personally port the last 10%. With over 20 sites in production, 60 sites in dev, and approximately 3-5 new sites added each week now, all using a set of about 45 modules, we will not be updating right away. Hacking core is a last resort, but unfortunately is not so much an answer as it is a workaround (and one we will have to change a bunch of scripts to support).